# branch.io api error (response:400, Authentication failed)

Tags: api, branch.io

According to [this guide:](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/custom-exports)

Accessing via API > Endpoint Definitions > Tune (select tab)

POST `/v3/logs/advertisers/ADVERTISER_ID/exports/`
Host: `api.mobileapptracking.com/` to the address

header

`Content-Type` and `Access-Token` are set normally

When I run it I get the following error:

> {
> "error": {
> "message": "Authentication failed !",
> "code": 400
> }
> }

What is the cause of this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when you are making the API call using the access token set at the Branch Application Level. While making the API request, please ensure you use the Access Token of the Organization level instead.

Comment: Where can one find this "Access Token of the Organization level"?

Comment: I don't think you'll be using Tune API. If you are using Branch exports API, please create a new question with the sample cURL payload